# ServiceNow - How to get the list of possible categories for incident or change via API

Tags: api, integration, servicenow

How to get this list by using ServiceNow API?

[image]

Comment: What sort of API? 
Client-side Glide API? Server-side Glide API? REST API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is by using REST API, here is how the call will look like:

`https://yourinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=category`

If you are only interested in `label` the call will look like this:

`https://yourinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=category&sysparm_fields=label`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't clarify whether you're looking for client-side, server-side, or REST API, but here's the answer for server-side:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.get('e8caedcbc0a80164017df472f39eaed1');

gs.print(gr.category.getChoices());
```

This `getChoices()` API is a GlideElement API, so you call it on a field element in a server-side GlideRecord.

You can find this API documentation [here](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=jakarta&id=r_ScopedGlideElementGetChoices_String_dependent).